# devbridge groupBy when Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I'm using https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/
I want to get results grouped by category when using ajax.
this only work when using: **lookup: teams** like this:

```
var teams =  [
{ value: 'Chicago Blackhawks', data: { category: 'NHL', link: 'website.com' } },
      { value: 'Chicago Bulls',  data: { category: 'NBA', link: 'site.com' } }
    ];
```

but i want to use it with **"serviceUrl:"** (ajax).

This is my PHP output:

```
    $suggestions = "[{ value: 'Chicago Blackhawks', data: { category: 'NHL', link: 'website.com' } },
          { value: 'Chicago Bulls',  data: { category: 'NBA', link: 'site.com' } }
        ]";    
return json_encode($suggestions);
```

but it troughs and javascript error: "TypeError: e is undefined"

Thanks.